# Android - Handling errors in fragment's onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got a fragment which is supposed to receive arguments in it's `onCreateView` method.

What is the correct way to handle errors in that case? If the arguments are null or I get an illegal argument, how can I stop the fragment from being created?

Comment: Isn't it easier to always pass the correct arguments?

Comment: If only users could always be trusted..

Comment: You can make an API for your users that first checks the arguments and, if correct, proceeds with the fragment creation.

Answer (score 0):

First check `getArgument()` is null or not if it is null then remove fragment using `FragmentManager`

```
if(getArgument()==null){

  getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

Comment: I'll try this now. Just for curiosity - I tried using getActivity().onBackPressed() and got an illegal state exception. why is that and why is that different from your answer?

Comment: may be your fragment is not attached